# Is there a combined plain+bold+italic+bolditalic TeX font available as one TTF file?

Tags: fonts, truetype

I am using a GUI control that supports only 1 font. I'd like to find a single font file that combines TeX's main font's plain, bold, italic, and bold-italic font in one font file for use with that GUI control.

So for instance, characters 32-127 are plain, 128-191 are bold, etc.

Does such a thing exist anywhere?

(Note, this is for English-only text, and not Unicode obviously.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It would be helpful if you provided a bit more information about your system setup. E.g., do your write using Plain TeX or LaTeX commands? Are you using the pdftex, xetex, luatex, or context TeX engines (or some entirely different TeX engine)? Answers to font-related questions depend very much on the TeX format and TeX engine that's being used.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think such a font exists. You could setup such a font using virtual fonts, but that still has the problem where you have map input such as "hello" to different output characters, depending on the current "font" (bold, italic...). You can do that with XeTeX and LuaTeX.

So the answer is 'no' but it can be simulated.